# Как можно передать трехмерный динамический типа string массив в класс?

Tags: c++

При передаче 3 мерного динамического массива получались ошибки при передаче его в функцию

```
 // main.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>   
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include <comdef.h>

#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include "raport.h"
using namespace std;





int main()
{


    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    string  WeyList[3] = { "D:\\report\\09_09_2018.txt",
        "D:\\report\\09_10_2018.txt",
        "D:\\report\\09_11_2018.txt" };
    int WeyListInt = 3;

    ifstream file(WeyList[0]);
    int strintRaport = 0;
    if (file.is_open())
    {


        string line;

        while (getline(file, line))
        {

            strintRaport++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Не подсчитано" << endl;
    }

    string ***RaportData = new string**[WeyListInt];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < WeyListInt; ++i)
    {
        RaportData[i] = new string*[strintRaport];
        for (size_t j = 0; j < strintRaport; ++j)
        {
            RaportData[i][j] = new string[5];
        }
    }





    raport Raport;
    Raport.OpenInputReport(RaportData,WeyList);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

2) raport.h

```
 #pragma once

    class raport
    {
    public:
        raport();
        void OpenInputReport(string ***RaportData,string WeyList[]);
        ~raport();
    private:

    };
```

3)raport.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "raport.h"

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

raport::raport()
{
}

void raport::OpenInputReport(string ***RaportData,string WeyList[])
{
    int j = 0;
    for (size_t t = 0; t <= 2; t++)
    {
        ifstream file(WeyList[t]);

        if (file.is_open())
        {
            cout << "" << endl;

            string line;

            while (getline(file, line))
            {
                istringstream iss(line);

                string token;
                int i = 0;
                while (getline(iss, token, '\t')) {

                    RaportData[t][j][i] = token;
                    i++;
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
        }
    }
}



raport::~raport()
{
}
```

> ```
> 1>------ Сборка начата: проект: Laba2, Конфигурация: Release Win32 ------
> 1>Laba2.cpp
> 1>c:\users\aleksandr\source\repos\laba2\laba2\raport.h(7): error C2061: синтаксическая ошибка: идентификатор "string"
> 1>c:\users\aleksandr\source\repos\laba2\laba2\laba2.cpp(55): warning C4018: <: несоответствие типов со знаком и без знака
> 1>c:\users\aleksandr\source\repos\laba2\laba2\laba2.cpp(58): warning C4018: <: несоответствие типов со знаком и без знака
> 1>c:\users\aleksandr\source\repos\laba2\laba2\laba2.cpp(69): error C2660: raport::OpenInputReport: функция не принимает 2 аргументов
> 1>c:\users\aleksandr\source\repos\laba2\laba2\raport.h(7): note:  см. объявление "raport::OpenInputReport"
> 1>raport.cpp
> 1>c:\users\aleksandr\source\repos\laba2\laba2\raport.h(7): error C2061: синтаксическая ошибка: идентификатор "string"
> 1>c:\users\aleksandr\source\repos\laba2\laba2\raport.cpp(16): error C2511: void raport::OpenInputReport(std::string ***,std::string []): перегруженная функция-член не найдена в "raport"
> 1>c:\users\aleksandr\source\repos\laba2\laba2\raport.h(4): note:  см. объявление "raport"
> 1>Сборка проекта "Laba2.vcxproj" завершена с ошибкой.
> ========== Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
> ```

Comment: показывайте как передаете и какие ошибки возникают.

Comment: Похоже, вы что-то делаете не так. Иными словами, с уверенностью можно сказать, что у вас что-то не получается.

Comment: Это не вопрос, а информация. Как объявлен массив, функция, как вы его создаете, как передаете, какие ошибки... Ничего же не написали. "У меня температура" - и что вам врач сможет посоветовать?

Comment: @Harry ... Медики говорят "Выпейте антибиотиков"

Comment: Какие "ошибки"? Компиляции? Выполнения? Еще чего-то? Что за бессмысленная фраза: "получаю ошибки"?

Comment: [Обязательная шутка про three star programmer.](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: @AnT А ты посмотри в 3)там я не смог отделить

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'd rather have three-star programming than an overabundance of typedefs. Especially typedefs of pointers. Ugh. -- wrl
Только я те понял Three-star code naturally comes up when you need to use an ordered index an array of pointers to strings (in that we ask for a position in the array, not for the string itself). The strings are of type char const *. The data block is of type char const *const *const [02]. The index block is of type char const *const *const *const [02].

Comment: одна из ошибок, `raport.h` инклудится первее `string`

Comment: Советую вам антибиотик - `vector<vector<vector<string>>>`. Смешивать raw pointers и string, гм...

Comment: @Artem Rachmaninov инкапсуляции я не вижу там

Comment: @ Harry  Мне с этим также трудно

Comment: @Artem Rachmaninov и самое не приятное в передаче

Comment: Самое странное это то что если я не создаю файлы raport.h raport.cpp  и все записую в стартовый файлик все работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каким образом вы хотите узнать размер данных. Эта информация будет потеряна. Но, для не динамического массива.

```
template<size_t X, size_t Y, size_t Z>
void fuu(int(&data)[X][Y][Z] ){
   //какой то код
}
```

Или вот так передавая размер явно

```
 int fuu(std::string*** data, size_t X,size_t Y, size_t Z){
                for(int x =0; x < X; ++x )
                     for(int y =0; y < Y; ++y )
                         for(int z =0; z < Z; ++z ){
                             std::cout << data[x][y][z] << "\n";
                         }
    }
```

Или используя vector.